# Novice Django question about object relationship

Tags: python, django

I am having some troubles understanding the object relationships in Django.  I wrote this:

```
 from django.db import models

class Community(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200) #arbitrary max length

class Category(models.Model):
    community = models.ForeignKey(Community)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200) #arbitrary max length

class Detail_View(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    detailView = models.CharField(max_length=200) #arbitrary max length
    website = models.CharField(max_length=200) #arbitrary max length
```

Each community should be able to have several Categories that are associated with it and each category should be able to have several Detail_Views associated with it.  I can do what I want with Communities, but as soon as I try to add a Category or Detail View, it screws up.  For example, if I say:

```
c = Community.objects.get(id=1)
c.category_set.create(category = "FooBar")
```

I get an error that says, "DatabaseError: table Content_Management_System_category has no column named category"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably haven't run `python manage.py syncdb` recently, or you did but you changed some table/models.Model definitions.

Try dropping your database, creating it, and running syncdb again. That is, if you don't have any important data in there.

You can also do `python manage.py reset <appname>`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you forgot to run syncdb after adding Category and/or Detail_View to your models.py

Or that because you have a field and the table name is Category, the models is getting messed up.

Try changing your category field to name in the class Category.  Same with detail_view